# MySql get list of unique words from table where values in a field separated with comma

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I am not sure if this is possible with pure SQL (MySQL) but I will ask anyway. I have a table like this:

```
ID    TAGS
-----------------------------
1     word1,word2,word3
2     word2,word4
3     word3,word5,word6,word7
...
```

I would like to select a all unique words from tags field, to get out something like this:

```
TAGS
-----
word1
word2
word3
word4
word5
word6
word7
```

Comment: Is there a maximum number of words in the `tags` column?

Comment: This is much easier to do at the application level.

Comment: The filed itself is of type text, so its limited to what can be hold inside this type

Comment: @Strawberry yes that's whay I was thinking too, but asked anyway...

Comment: I suggest redesigning your database.   As you can see, your current data model makes your tags pretty unuseable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this in SQL, although it is not pretty.

```
select distinct reverse(substring_index(reverse(substring_index(tags, ',', n.n)), ',', 1)) as word
from t cross join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2 as n union all select 3 as n union all select 4 as n) n
having word is not null
```

You need to be sure that the subquery `n` has at least the number of words in each tags.

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3db7e/7) is the SQLFiddle that demonstrates this.

This is cross joining the original data with sequential numbers.  It then picks out the nth value from the tags strings, using `substring_index()`.

To get the maximum number of tags, you can do:

```
select max(length(tags) - length(replace(tags, ',', 1))+1
from t
```

Comment: this doesn't work, I am getting 2 rows, one empty and second NULL.

Comment: @PrimozRome . . . The expression should have been `substring_index(substring_index(. . .))`.  I fixed that problem and added a `having` clause to eliminate the `NULL`.

Comment: looks better, however it only outputs one row = word1

Comment: @PrimozRome . . . fixed and demonstrated to work on SQL Fiddle.

Comment: still not working correctly. I am not getting all the values.

Comment: yes I can see but it does not work on my database... of-course I have different table names and fields. I have changed that in your SQL but it only fetched out 2 values ... should be at list 10

Comment: Did you add more values to the `n` subquery?  This version only picks out the first 3.  You probably just need more `union all` statements there.

Comment: What does that mean exactly, because I can't get it quite to understand this with n? Do I need to add as many as I have different word values? That is useless here, since the list of different words can be infinite... ?

Comment: @PrimozRome . . . as I thought I explained in the answer, you need as many "n" as the maximum number of tags in a row.  Each "n" is picking out the "nth" word from the list.  So, with three values, you get the first three words.  With values up to 10, you would get the first ten words in each list and so on.

Comment: Ok I get it... this is not then a right solution here as the number of words can increase meaning I would need to alter the query when new tag is inserted.

Comment: @PrimozRome . . . No.  It is based on the number of tags in one row.  Not on the total number of words.  So, if there are at most 5 tags in one row, you can have 10,000 words and it will work.

Comment: I will accept this as the answer for my problem, since it solves my problem relatively easy and fast.

Answer (score 0):

The only way i can think of doing this in the database is with a stored procedure, this stored procedure will iterate over every row, extract and analyze its contents, althogh, it won't be very efficient.