# MySQL: How can I obtain a distinct list of words from a string column using a stored procedure

Tags: mysql

I've been agonising over this for the past day and a half, and while I've attempted to [write my own function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19583981/in-mysql-how-can-i-use-the-replace-function-when-defining-a-stored-procedure) using [examples that people gave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16153958/mysql-get-list-of-unique-words-from-table-where-values-in-a-field-sepparated-wit), it's been incredibly difficult to do seeing as the strings I'm obtaining might be anything from 30 words to 1000 words long

I've a database that looks something like this

```
|NewsItemID|NewsItemString                  |
============================================
| 1        | This is the first news item    |
| 2        | This is the second news item   |
| 3        | This is the third news article |
============================================
```

How can I use a stored procedure to end up with a list like this:

```
|Word    |
==========
|This    |
|is      |
|the     |
|first   |
|news    |
|item    |
|second  |
|third   |
|article |
```

Comment: You should really be doing this through an application, not a DBMS.

Comment: Five thousand articles a week. I'm trying to speed up the process as this is time critical. :(

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Where I've seen this question before, the answer has invariably been 'handle it at the application level'. Assuming 'articles' are no larger than, say, the complete works of Shakespeare, then I'm guessing that 5000 a week is trivial for a modern machine.

Comment: @TheMightyLlama What's your reservation about using an application or writing a script to do this?

Comment: The question is: how are this articles entered in the database? By an application, i guess. So i think that carrying out the solution at app level is not a madness

Comment: Yep, you guys are right. I'll do this at the application.

Comment: In my case, I don't have access to the app that creates the data